# How do i tell my app "stop running" after set amount rounds?

Tags: c++

So i'm making a turn based dice game that's modeled after this game called "underground chinchiro" which was taken from an anime called "Kaiju". I need to set a limit to my program so that it only runs for a set number of rounds, 
 I'm only a beginner in coding so sorry for anything unusual you see in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void roll_3_dice(int &dice1, int &dice2, int &dice3) 
{
    dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dice3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    return;
}


int main()
{
int cash = 90000;
int wager; 
int r;


//dealer's die
int dealer1;
int dealer2;
int dealer3;

// your die
int mdice1;
int mdice2;
int mdice3;


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
cout << "Wager up boy!"<< endl;
cin >> wager;
while (wager < 100 || wager > 90000)
{
cout << "Minimum wager is 100; Maximum wager is 90000 ";
cin >> wager;
}

cout << "You wagered: " << wager << endl;
cout << "You have " << cash - wager << " remaining" << endl;
cash = cash - wager;

cout << endl;
cout << "Dealer will now roll the dice" << endl;

roll_3_dice(dealer1, dealer2, dealer3);


cout << "Dealer rolled the following: " << endl;
cout << dealer1 << "-" << dealer2 << "-" << dealer3 << endl;

cout << "It's your turn to roll the dice." << endl;
cout << endl; 
cout << "Press any key to roll the dice" << endl;
cin >> r;

roll_3_dice(mdice1, mdice2, mdice3);

cout << "You rolled the following: " << endl;
cout << mdice1 << "-" << mdice2 << "-" << mdice3 << endl;


system ("pause");
 }
}
```

Comment: loop...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at for loops. For loops will allow you to run your code for a set number iteration.

e.g. iterate over some code 7 times.

```
int number_of_iterations = 7;
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_iterations; i++) {
    // Your code that you would like to iterate over goes here.
 }
```

**EDIT:**
As has been specified by the OP (in comments below), the issue is appears to be with the program not stopping to receive input from the user through each iteration of the for loop.

This could be for a number of reasons. My best guess would be that the stdin buffer is not clear and that `std::cin` continues to read in from the buffer. This could be solver by calling `cin.clear()` before reading in your input.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, i tried using a for loop but it displays all iterations immediately, i need it to pause every iteration cause i need the user to enter a wager every iteration, that's where im confused. Sorry bout that

Comment: @elburatski could you post what you tried. i.e. you for loop version?

Comment: basically i just added for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) just below mdice3

Comment: @elburatski ok so with your updated code. It works as expected on my system which leads me to beleive that `std::cin` may not be clearing. I will update my answer.

Comment: @elburatski If the suggested above does not work for you. I apologize as I cannot help you further. Your problem is not reproducible on my system. My only additional comment would be to 100% make sure that your code compiled before testing again.

Answer (score 0):

is time to learn how to use constants...

define one doing

```
const int max_round = 5;
```

and the do a `while` so long round is `<=` than `max_round`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pretty unclear. Edit your code, find the section where problems occurring and paste that part only.

like:

```
while(cin>>wager)
{
   if(condition fails) 
   { 
       break; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Using a for loop displays all the iterations without asking for a wager, all it does it take the first entered amount and subtracts it to int cash, i need my app to let the user enter different wagers every iteration.

Comment: mmm I think its working correctly for me if I take int value for r.

Comment: what I guess you are pressing any key instead of an int value  
changing data type of ```int r``` to ```char r``` or taking only int after  
"Press any key to roll the dice" may help