# How to write a function that checks combinations of 3 numbers?

Tags: c++

I'm currently making a 2 player dice game and i need to create a function that checks the value of the dice combination you rolled. Ex: I rolled 3-4-2, I need the function to check if there is a payout for 3-4-2, example rolls and their payouts + code below

```
 //Rolling 1-1-1 would give you 5x your wager
 //Rolling 3 of the same number (except 1-1-1) would give you 2x wager
 //Rolling 3 different numbers (ex 1-4-6) would give you 1x your wager
 //Rolling 1-2-3 makes the player automatically lose a round and pay opposing Player 2x wager

    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void roll_3_dice(int &dice1, int &dice2, int &dice3) 
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dice3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    return;
}


int main()
{
    int cash = 90000;
    int wager; 
    int r;


    //dealer's die
    int dealer1;
    int dealer2;
    int dealer3;

    // your die
    int mdice1;
    int mdice2;
    int mdice3;


    while ( cash > 100 || round < 10 )
    {
        cout << "Set your wager: "<< endl;
        cin >> wager;

        while (wager < 100 || wager > 90000)
        {
            cout << "Minimum wager is 100; Maximum wager is 90000 ";
            cin >> wager;
        }

        cout << "You wagered: " << wager << endl;
        cout << "You have " << cash - wager << " remaining" << endl;
        cash = cash - wager;

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Dealer will now roll the dice" << endl;

        roll_3_dice(dealer1, dealer2, dealer3);

        cout << "Dealer rolled the following: " << endl;
        cout << dealer1 << "-" << dealer2 << "-" << dealer3 << endl;

        cout << "It's your turn to roll the dice." << endl;
        cout << endl; 
        cout << "Press any key to roll the dice" << endl;
        cin >> r;

        roll_3_dice(mdice1, mdice2, mdice3);

        cout << "You rolled the following: " << endl;
        cout << mdice1 << "-" << mdice2 << "-" << mdice3 << endl;

        system ("pause`enter code here`");
    }
}
```

Comment: You will just have to write lots of if-statements, like `if (dice1 == 1 && dice2 ==1 && dice3 == 1) result = 5 * wager;`. etc.

Comment: After rolling, sort the dice in ascending order. That will make it easier to detect sequences such as 1,2,3 since you don't have to also check for e.g. 3,2,1 or 2,1,3

Comment: @JasonLang Can you help me with sorting? I dont really know how to sort...

Comment: compare the first two numbers, swap them if #1 is greater than #2. then do that for #2 and #3, then for #1 and #2 again. This ensures that three numbers are in ascending order.

Comment: to swap two numbers, you need to make a "temp" variable to hold #1, the set #1 to #2, then put the temp in #2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i tell my app "stop running" after set amount rounds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293796/how-do-i-tell-my-app-stop-running-after-set-amount-rounds)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write your algorithm on a paper first, like you did in the comments on top of the code.

Then, ask yourself what you need to process the final wager ? As in parameters. For instance, in your case, you may need a function which takes the initial wager, and the values of the three dices as entry parameters.

This function would return the final wager.

Finally, in the function itself, organize the algorithm by priority rules.
If 1-1-1 gives you 5x your wager, then it's a particular case which can be isolated at the top of the function maybe, and you can return 5 x initial wager directly, without any need to process further operations.
You'll just have to organize the different cases with if statements, regarding the priorities of each statement.
The 1-1-1 case has to come before the "same number for each dice" for example.

Hope this helps.